# Want to gift stock shares to non us student. What do I need to do?

Tags: stocks, non-resident, gifts

Want to gift shares of stock to a non-US students studying in US.  What do I need to do?  What does the student need to do?

Comment: What citizenship is this student? How many shares of stock are you gifting?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do that is to transfer the equivalent cash sum to one of their accounts, have them move it into a trading/investment account and purchase the shares themselves from there. I always seek the lowest commission/overhead methods when doing anything like that. Regarding tax in the US I really cant comment.

Answer (score 2):

It depend on how they are held.

## Paper Stock Certificates

If you have actual paper stock certificates, you can hand them over and complete a stock transfer form.

## Securities in a US Brokerage Account

The shares can be transferred by your broker to the recipients' US brokerage account.  Most likely they would be transferred through the FOP (free of payment) transfer system.  Your broker will be able to help you through this.
If the recipients do not have a brokerage account, they would need to set one up.  It might be quicker if it is the same brokerage firm, but doesn't have to be.